# It is possible to reduce or eliminate the space between rows of a 3*3 matrix?

Tags: java

I have a matrix which I am trying to print. How to reduce the space between two rows of matrix `a`?

```
for(int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
        System.out.println(a[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I fixed your formatting but not your errors as that would change the post. You might want to check that out on your own.

Comment: If you don't want new lines don't use `println` (print with new line) use `print`

Answer (score 1):

You are printing with `println` every time. That's why you are getting new lines after each number when printing. To print a matrix, I'd have liked to print this way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numOfRows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < numOfColumns; j++) {
        if (j != 0) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.printf("%4d", a[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

For example: for `{{1,243,3}, {55,12,676}, {45,232,545}}` matrix output will be:

```
   1  243    3
  55   12  676
  45  232  545
```

Answer (score 0):

println is print with new lines. what you want is

```
for(int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
        System.out.print(a[i][j] + "\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```